# Target amplitude in FMCW Radar not same as number of samples

Tags: range

I have estimated the range of target by using FMCW radar. The value is correctly estimated along the range axis in the plot. But I want the target's amplitude to be similar to the number of samples i.e. L in my code, that needs to be fixed.
I cannot locate the problem. What could be the issue?

```
clc,clear;
%% radar specs
radar_specs_fc = 77e9; radar_specs_c = 3e8;
radar_specs_lambda = radar_specs_c/radar_specs_fc;
radar_specs_fs = 150e6; radar_specs_delta_t = 1/radar_specs_fs;
radar_specs_num_chirp_smpls = 512;                                             % number of chirp samples
radar_specs_Tchirp = (0:radar_specs_num_chirp_smpls-1)/radar_specs_fs;
radar_specs_Tc = radar_specs_Tchirp(end);
radar_specs_range_res = 1;
radar_specs_chirpBW = radar_specs_c/(2*radar_specs_range_res);
radar_specs_chirpslope = radar_specs_chirpBW/radar_specs_Tc;
radar_specs_num_TPRI_smpls = 1024;                                              % number of TPRI samples
radar_specs_TPRI = (0:radar_specs_num_TPRI_smpls-1)/radar_specs_fs;             % TPRI including idle time and chirp time samples
%% user defined range ,velocity and angle of targets
num_tgts = 1;
tgt_rng = 100; tgt_vel = 30; tgt_angle = 45;
tgt_delay = 2*tgt_rng/radar_specs_c;
%% alpha_tau_prime
alpha_tau_prime = exp(-1i*2*pi*radar_specs_fc*tgt_delay).*exp(1i*pi*radar_specs_chirpslope*(tgt_delay.^2));
% alpha_tau_prime = 1;
%% Range freq / Fast time
freq_rng = (radar_specs_chirpslope.*tgt_delay + 2.*tgt_vel/radar_specs_lambda)*radar_specs_delta_t;
%% Doppler freq / Slow time
freq_dopp = 2*radar_specs_fc*(radar_specs_TPRI(end)).*tgt_vel/radar_specs_c; %((radar_specs_num_TPRI_smpls-1)/radar_specs_fs)
%% Antenna parameters
antenna_M = 32; m_set = 0:antenna_M-1;                           % Define the number of  Tx antennas
antenna_N = 32; n_set = 0:antenna_N-1;                           % Define the number of  Rx antennas
%% Spatial frequency at the TX antenna
antenna_dt = radar_specs_lambda/2;
freq_tx = antenna_dt*sin(deg2rad(tgt_angle)) /radar_specs_lambda;
%% Spatial frequency at the RX antenna
antenna_dr = radar_specs_lambda/2;
freq_rx = antenna_dr*sin(deg2rad(tgt_angle)) /radar_specs_lambda;
%%
L = length(radar_specs_Tchirp);                                  % number of samples per chirp
K = 32; k_set = 0:K-1;                                           % number of chirps
for n_idx = 1:length(n_set)                                 % receiver antenna index
        n = n_set(n_idx);
       for m_idx = 1:length(m_set)                          % transmitter antenna index
            m = m_set(m_idx);
            l_set = (0:L-1)';                        
           data_outputs_a_n_s(:,:,m_idx,n_idx) = alpha_tau_prime*exp(-1j*2*pi*freq_rng.*l_set)...
                            *exp(-1j*2*pi*freq_dopp.*k_set)*exp(-1j*2*pi*(freq_tx*m + freq_rx*n));
       end
          data_outputs_ans_N_antenna(:,:,n_idx) = sum(data_outputs_a_n_s(:,:,:,n_idx),3);                  
end
% power of the signal
pow_data_outputs_ans_N_antenna = abs((data_outputs_ans_N_antenna).^2);
mesh(abs(pow_data_outputs_ans_N_antenna(:,:,1)));
```